# TSQL - Parsing XML Help, searching for specific value

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xml-parsing

Can anyone help me with the correct TSQL to parse the following xml.  Say i wanted to find the item with a value of "y" for the name element, but i want to get the value of of "value" element, which is "2" in the example below.

```
Declare @XML xml

set @XML ='
<Test>
<items>
<item>
<name>x</name>
<value>1</value>
</item>
<item>
<name>y</name>
<value>2</value>
</item>
</items>
</Test>'

--i am stuck here
selecct @XML.value('Test/items/....")
```

Result would be "2" by searching for "y".

Is this possible?

can someone help with the syntax?  thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 select @xml.value('((test/items/item)[2]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

Breakdown:

```
(test/items/item)[2]  -- find the second instance of an item tag under a test tag

((test/items/item)[2]/value)[1] -- then find the first instance of a value tag under that
```

The value function cannot be given any expression which can even in theory return more than one value. If in doubt put brackets around it like this `(some-expression-here)[1]`.

To find the value corresponding to a given name:

```
 select @xml.value('((test/items/item)[name="y"][1]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

Comment: Hi Ben, many thanks for your reply.  This would work if i knew what i was looking for was in the 2nd instance of the tag.  But what if i didn't?  so i want to search the the value "y" in the name tag and return the value of the value tag.  Probably should have named the tags better..sorry.

Comment: Hi Ben, ur edit looks like what i'm looking for, but when i run it, i get a null returned
`Declare @XML xml 

set @XML =' 
<test> 
<items> 
<item> 
<name>x</name> 
<value>1</value> 
</item> 
<item> 
<name>y</name> 
<value>2</value> 
</item> 
</items> 
</test>' 

select @xml.value('((test/items)[name="y"][1]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') 
`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use XQuery (designed to query XML data) for this.  TSQL supports a subset of it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075%28SQL.90%29.aspx